# Globally turn sound on or off

Tags: android

Is there a way to control the sound level of your app "globally"?

I don't want to control the sound at each individual location where it is used, I want an on/off button, for example, in a settings page, to do this for all sounds in the app.

Comment: You need to manage Audio Focus [See this](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just have a global, boolean variable that is set in the settings page, and use if statements before the sounds.

Comment: This does make sense, but I want to try to avoid adding logic at each sound. May need to resort to this eventually if I find no other solution